# 404 error for Google Tag Manager

Tags: get, google-tag-manager

Google Tag Manager told me to put this underneath the opening `body` tag.

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Now I'm getting this 404 not found for GET:

```
GET http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX
```

I implemented the code last night. Does this just take time or is this something that needs to be fixed? If the latter, how would I fix it?

Comment: Have you published at least the first version of you container?

Comment: @Sundrique I'm not sure. How can I check?

Comment: Go to Container -> Overview, and click blue "Publish" button in the top right corner. Thank click "Create version and publish" in a popup.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

You need to [publish](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107163?hl=en) a version of your container. If it is not published, the request will return a 404 error.

> To publish your current workspace:
>
> 1. Click **Submit** at the top right hand side of the screen. The **Submit Changes** screen will appear, with options to publish the container and save a version of your container.
> 2. Select **Publish and Create Version** if it is not already selected.
> 3. Review the **Workspace Changes** section to see if your configuration appears as you expect.
> 4. Enter a **Version Name** and **Version Description**.
> 5. If you have Tag Manager configured to use multiple environments, use the **Publish to Environment** section to select which environment you'd like to publish to.
> 6. Click **Publish**.

Comment: Note that you may not see the options for publishing if your user does not have "Publish" rights on the container - even if you're an Admin.

Comment: After making changes in the workspace, you will need to go back to your environments and publish each one to the appropriate version.

Comment: This is the correct solution but for cases when users already have the container published, the reason for the 404 is that preview mode expired. You can fix this by disabling the preview mode. 

So there are 2 causes for the 404 error: 
1. Unpublished container
2. Expired preview mode in GTM Check https://analyticshelp.io/blog/fix-google-tag-manager-not-loading-404-error/ for more details on this

Comment: As of June 2021 new GTM containers automatically create a published (empty) version to avoid this problem. Obviously you still need to publish again to see any changes you make.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue even after publishing and got it fixed by simply deleting the subdomain "www" from the tag manager domain "https://googletagmanager.com" instead of "https://www.googletagmanager.com"

Seems the problem is that the DNS is blocking www. or the subdomain doesn't reroute properly to our region!

Comment: Wasn't expecting this to be the solution but it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: This solved the 404 error, but then the "Preview and Debug" mode didn't work.
I restored the `www.` subdomain and curiously everything works as expected.
Maybe we just have to wait until the changes get propagated...

Comment: Interesting, this was the case for me as well. Definitely region based, as my colleagues in the UK are not affected. Do you think it's safe to remove the `www.` bit in the GTM snippets?

Comment: @VojtaHejda can't guarantee but have been using it without the www. for 2.5 years and didn't have an issue

Answer (score 9):

My issue was that had AdBlock enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it helped when I leave Preview and launch it again. As I figured out my preview was somehow "outdated".

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, **you don't need to publish the container** to fix the Error 404 when you first create the container. You can just do a preview and the error 404 should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Once you done any changes on Google tag manager make sure you publish it. if you are not publishing changes on google tag manager then this issue will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share my encounter of a rather similar problem.

I noticed the optimize.js script in the GTM was hitting 404 on the console and the GA stopped tracking visits for a while. The optimize.js is a tag from Google and for no apparent reason, it stopped tracking. And, it was a dependent tag for the GA tag to run.
[image]

After I disabled the optimize.js tag and removed it as the dependent tag on the GA tag, the GA starts to track again and I no longer get the 404 error on GTM.

Just thought it might be helpful info.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

GTM can return a 404 when trying to load a container that isn't enabled for debugging.  Debugging can be enabled by checking the `Enable Debugging by Default` checkbox under Admin > Environments > Actions > Edit Settings > Environment Configuration.  That fixed it in my case.

Answer (score -1):

You must publish the container once you create it. It's doesn't matter the container is empty, just publish it.