# Remarketing Tag Error : net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: tags, google-ads-api

Can you help me fix this error before I add my remarketing code into . But tag assitant show "red" color and show : "

> An error occured while the tag was fired: net::ERR_ABORTED

and

> Error while sending request: net::ERR_ABORTED

I called to google supporter and they say " my website block request from google".But i can't fix this.

this my site : http://luongyenancora.com

please hepl me ! thanks

Comment: i solved this problem ! by fix my web site eror when change http to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've entered at least one tag and published a version of your container in Google Tag Manager (the green box in the top right of the interface should say Live Version).

I was a bit of an eager beaver and checked on the tag using Tag Assistant before doing this, and it turned out that this was my problem.  You'd think Google could do something make the process a bit more intuitive!

After a bit of searching and coming up with nothing but suggestions to turn off my AdBlock, I looked in my Inspector/DevTools at Network requests and noticed the request to the `gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXXX` script was coming up with a 404 error.

That lead me to this answer (contains more detailed instructions for publishing): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29666416

After publishing, this error went away and the tag now works properly.