# Create Google Tag manager Trigger that fires when {{variable}} == 'false' with GTM API v2

Tags: google-api, google-tag-manager

I am trying to create a Google Tag Manager trigger using the [GTM API v2](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/triggers/create).

I'm trying to achieve the following:
I want  a trigger to fire on Page view in pages where the variable `Mobile or not` is `false`

[image: achieve the follo]

I tried to call the API with these parameters

```
{
  "name": "Desktop Users Test",
  "type": "pageview",
  "filter": [
    {
      "parameter": [
        {
          "type": "template",
          "value": "{{ Mobile or not }}",
          "key": "arg0"
        },
        {
          "type": "boolean",
          "value": "false",
          "key": "arg1"
        }
      ],
      "type": "equals"
    }
  ]
}
```

But it returning a `400 Bad Request` error with this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Unable to parse trigger data"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unable to parse trigger data"
 }
}
```

If I create a trigger with only name, type and empty filters it works

```
{
  "name": "Will work too",
  "type": "pageview",
  "filter": []
}

// will return a "200 OK" response
```

Please, what are the right parameters to create this trigger?

Comment: Did you see this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243170/404-error-for-google-tag-manager?answertab=oldest#tab-top) ?